# Change default "The {0} field is required" (ultimate solution?)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, viewmodel, modelbinders

Good day!

I've the following ViewModel class I use for login form:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

...

public class UserLogin : IDataErrorInfo
{           
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Login")]
    public string Login { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Remember Me")]
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }

    #region IDataErrorInfo Members

    // This will be a Model-level error
    public string Error
    {
        get
        {
            if (!WebUser.CanLogin(Login, Password))
            {
                return Resources.ValidationErrors.InvalidLoginPassword;
            }
            else
            {
                return String.Empty;
            }
        }
    }

    // All is handled by DataAnnotation attributes, just a stub for interface
    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
    #endregion

}
```

And this in `Global.asax`:

```
DefaultModelBinder.ResourceClassKey = "BinderMessages";
ValidationExtensions.ResourceClassKey = "BinderMessages";
```

The resource file `BinderMessages.resx` is placed inside App_GlobalResources it has two keys `InvalidPropertyValue` (which works) and `PropertyValueRequired` which doesn't and gives me default message.

Question: Is it possible to modify this message, or it's tied to DataAnnotations?

I've found many posts about this, but without solution. For now I just fallback to this:

```
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.ValidationErrors), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required")]
```

Comment: The problem left though, is what if you left Login and Password blank? The program aborts with object not set.

Comment: Why do you think so? The model binder will instantiate a `UserLogin` object instance anyway.

Comment: Almost 5 years and seems still not applicable. There are still only 4 keys that can be used in the resource file defined in the `global.asax`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a custom `ValidationAttribute` that extends `RequiredAttribute` and sets the values there.  Something like:

```
public class MyRequiredAttribute : RequiredAttribute
{
    public MyRequiredAttribute()
    {
         ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.ValidationErrors);
         ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required";
    }
}
```

Then decorate your Model with your custom attribute.

The default message is compiled into the DataAnnotations assembly in the resource file under `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Resources.DataAnnotationsResources.resources` and is `RequiredAttribute_ValidationError=The {0} field is required.`.  So to answer your question, yes, that message is part of DataAnnotations.

Edit: `PropertyValueRequired` is used for errors on null values with non-nullable types. As mentioned below `PropertyValueInvalid` is used for type conversion errors.

Comment: Thank for the response, that's a much better solution than mine (do you really mean `ActionFilterAttribute` and not data annotation attriube?). Is it possible to get to know why it doen't work?

Comment: Oops, yep.  Sorry about that.  I meant ValidationAttribute.  Edited.

Comment: Small note: `InvalidPropertyValue` is called when it fails to bind values to object fields (conversion errors), for example -- when it can't bind string value to int model field, that's happens before validation.

Comment: This solution properly displays my default English resources, but doesn't switch to use my *.es.resx when my UICulture is switched.

Comment: This seems like it causes unobtrusive validation to no longer be generated.  I suspect this is because MVC is hardcoded to look for the Required attribute instead of something less fragile.

Answer (score 1):

I've done an approach using a singleton class to provide the translations. You still need to derive all attributes as suggested by @bmancini. The upside with my approach is that you can use multiple string tables (or switch translation source) without having to modify any other logic.

Since my blog entry is rather large, I'll just provide a link:
http://blog.gauffin.org/2010/11/simplified-localization-for-dataannotations/

Comment: Your link died :(