# Customize required attribute

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I've been trying to custumize the required attribute using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370228/change-default-the-0-field-is-required-ultimate-solution) solution

But I get that I'm missing a directive with:

```
ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.ValidationErrors);
ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required";
```

`ErrorMessageResourceType` and `ErrorMessageResourceName`. What else do I need to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

They're both properties of the `ValidationAttribute` in the `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` dll. So you might need a reference there but you wouldn't get the `Required` attribute so it might be something else

If you're using `VB` and not `c#` then you'll have to type:

```
<Required(ErrorMessageResourceType := GetType(Resources.ValidationErrors),
          ErrorMessageResourceName := "Required")>
```

The c# one should look like:

```
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.ValidationErrors),
          ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required")]
```

Can you post your whole code for your `Required` attribute so that we can narrow it down?

Comment: I think VB uses < > not [ ] for attributes.